# WordPress Custom Template - Divi module shortcode displays as text

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, text, shortcode

I have written a head navigation using the full-width code module in Divi. It is in my Divi library as a global module and works perfectly with most of my pages, but not the ones that are using my **custom templates**.

The way I am displaying the module is by using it's shortcode at the bottom of my child theme's header.php right before the closing header tag:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[showmodule id="XXXX"]'); ?>`

where XXXX is the actual id. But on the pages using custom templates the module displays as plain text like so:

'[et_pb_section global_module="*my modules id*"][/et_pb_section]'

I have also tried changing the code to:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content','[showmodule id="XXXX"]');
```

however, the same issue occurs.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found a good method for this in a thread in the Divi Support Forum, which this dude also explains in a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJqcfz5NyZs

Once you get the global Module number from the URL when viewing it in the Divi Library, the shortcode syntax to load the global module in php is:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="###"][/et_pb_section]'); ?>
```

One drawback is that loading a module through a php template file does not allow it to be editable through the Visual Builder.

So, I made a modification to this so I could have an easier place to edit the global footer by adding it to my site's homepage Divi layout, then adding this snippet in my footer.php template file to load on the rest of the pages:

```
<?php if ( !is_front_page() ) : ?>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="2310"][/et_pb_section]'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This way I can easily have a client use the Visual Builder on the homepage to edit the global footer, instead of having to find it in the Divi Library, which they would likely forget and takes extra click to get there.

Comment: Divi now has a Divi Library where you can save modules and edit them, under Admin > Divi > Divi Library. Maybe this was not a feature at the time of answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding this code. It will solve your problem

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[showmodule id="my modules id"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. Unfortunately that's the same code I'd tried before. I wasn't clear when I put in the *my modules id* part. That was just supposed to be a placeholder for the real ID. I'll revise the question.